# Unable to read culture specific values

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, localization, internationalization

I working on a localization project and unable to read the value by local from the resource file.

I have a sample solution as below:

```
1. Web API project
2. Resources Project.
    - In resources project, I have 3 resource files de-DE, fr-FR, and en-US.
```

[image]

I am reading the resource key "Name" from the resource file, I am able to get the value from de-DE and en-US by setting culture value as below.

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult<IEnumerable<string>> Get()
    {
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("fr-FR");
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("fr-FR");
        var name = Employees.Name;
        return new string[] { name };
    }
```

However, When I try to read the key for fr-FR local, it is giving English value. 
The only difference is, the French resource file is present inside a folder and others are present at project level.

Comment: What are you getting and what are you exactly expecting to get? Is that really culture-specific? Why are you setting the culture of the current thread to `fr-FR` on the current thread while you are just accessing a property? It would also be interesting to see an example of different culture-specific data "as they are"

Comment: I have a key with "Name" in all resource files. I want to return the name-value based on culture user sends. Ex: If he sends de-DE, we need to send the value from the German file. If he sends, fr-FR, we need to send the value from the French file.

Answer (score 3):

The .NET resource system is based largely on convention; it expects resource files for specific cultures to be found at very specific paths.

- `Employees.resx` contains the neutral resources for the `Employees` container.
- `Employees.[culture].resx` contains the resources for the `Employees` container for a specific culture.

If you have a resource file in another folder, the resource-lookup system treats it as a separate resource. `fr-FR/Employees.fr-FR.resx` is the French resources for the `fr_FR.Employees` container.

To make your resources load correctly, you just need to put them in the same folder:

- `Employees.resx`
- `Employees.de-DE.resx`
- `Employees.fr-FR.resx`

Comment: Thanks, @Paul. I have tried an alternative and able to read the value. We just need to add below piece of code in the project file.                                  
                                                                                                     
<EmbeddedResource Update="fr-FR\Employees.fr-FR.resx">
      <ManifestResourceName>$(TargetName).%(Filename)</ManifestResourceName>
    </EmbeddedResource>